# Spring AOP advice is called twice

Tags: aop, spring-aop

I have the following Spring AOP advice and I can't find out why it is called twice:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspects {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingAspects.class);

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(public * com.A.B.C.service.impl.*.browse(..))",
            returning = "retVal")
    public Object onBrowse(DomainClass retVal) {
        logger.info("#######################Advice Called: +retVal);
        return null;
    }

}
```

The configuration is as simple as that:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy></aop:aspectj-autoproxy>

<bean id="loggingCASAspect" class="com.minervanetworks.xtv.stb.service.aspects.LoggingCASAspects"/>
```

I have also tried the following advice with the same result (called twice).

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut="@annotation(com.A.B.C.service.impl.LOG)", returning="retVal")
public Object onBrowse(JoinPoint jp, DomainClass retVal) {
    logger.info("#######################Advice called! " + jp.toLongString()
    + " Target: " + jp.getTarget()
    + " Signature: " + jp.getSignature()
    + " Kind: " + jp.getKind()
    + " This: " + jp.getThis()
    + " Source Location: " + jp.getSourceLocation());

    return null;
}
```

The debug info from the above logger is:

```
2011-10-26 11:56:01,887 [INFO][com.A.B.C.service.aspects.LoggingAspects] #######################Advice called! execution(public abstract com.A.B.C.domain.DomainClass com.A.B.C.service.ContentManager.browse(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Boolean)) Target: com.A.B.C.service.impl.ContentManagerImpl@62ad191 Signature: DomainClass com.A.B.C.service.ContentManager.browse(String,String,String,Boolean) Kind: method-execution This: com.A.B.C.service.impl.ContentManagerImpl@62ad191 Source Location: org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint$SourceLocationImpl@d324de2
```

It is displayed twice with exactly the same values.

Comment: I hate asking the obvious, but is the method being called twice?

Comment: That was the first thing, I did check. The method is called only once.
Sorry that I missed to mention that in the original question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**1. hint**

Do you use JavaConfig or xml?
If you're using both, it could be that the Aspect is being processed two times by the Spring IoC container.

**2. hint**

I don't annotate aspects with @Component annoation, try to remove it, maybe because of that is being processed twice by Spring.

Comment: I exactly have same issue. However if I remove @Component, it stops logging. Following is the class

Comment: `@Component` (or another Spring stereotype) is required for component scanning. If you were able to fix the issue by removing this annotation some other wiring mechanism than component scanning must be effective.

Comment: Another hint: You would want to keep @Component if your AOP class was in another moduke/project. It will execute once as expected.

Answer (score 3):

I found that the advice can be called twice if the aspect is declared as request-scoped. In this case the same bean is registered twice as an interceptor with different names: `someAspect` and `scopedTarget.someAspect`. I solved this issue by making the Aspect a singleton.

Version: Spring Boot 2.0.x

Answer (score 1):

It haven't been mentioned, but take care that your pointcut is not matching other method calls.

For example in my case, I was calling different Beans :
**Bean A** -> **Bean B** -> Bean C

I wanted to add an aspect to Bean A, but Bean B method signature was also matching the poincut, resolving in 2 methods calls.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue caused by the annotation below.

```
@Aspect
@Service
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
```

The solution was to remove the Scope request annotation.

```
@Aspect
@Service
```

Answer (score 0):

for me,remove the @Component is working

--before--

```
@Aspect
@Component
class Aop {
@Around("@annotation(*.*.*.*)")
fun around(pjp: ProceedingJoinPoint):Any?{
    do  something
  }
}
```

--after--

```
@Aspect    
class Aop {
@Around("@annotation(*.*.*.*)")
fun around(pjp: ProceedingJoinPoint):Any?{
    do  something
  }
}
```