# Spring AOP @Around annotation called twice if overriding abstract method with generics

Tags: java, spring, generics, aspectj, spring-aop

I have an `@Around` annotation processor that extends a base class which has some annotation handling methods. The base class takes some generic class types so it can use those in some protected methods and in the abstract method definition.

If the abstract method (which gets decorated with the `@Around` annotation in the sub-class) uses one of the generic types in its definition, then the sub-class implementation gets called twice.

Base Abstract Class:

```
public abstract class AnnotationProcessor<TargetType, AnnotationType extends Annotation> {

    public abstract Object processAnnotation(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, TargetType targetType) throws Throwable;

    protected AnnotationType getAnnotationSettings(JoinPoint joinPoint, Class<AnnotationType> type) throws AnnotationProcessingException
    {
        //...elided... do some stuff
    }
}
```

Sub-Class:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class SubProcessing extends AnnotationProcessor<HasSomeInfo, MyAnnotation> {

    @Override
    @Around("@annotation(MyAnnotation) && target(hasSomeInfo)")
    public Object processAnnotation(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, HasSomeInfo hasSomeInfo) throws Throwable
    {
        //Run their method
        Object methodReturn = joinPoint.proceed();

        //Get the annotation so we can use its values
        MyAnnotation annotation = getAnnotationSettings( joinPoint, MyAnnotation.class);

        System.out.println( "Called " + hasSomeInfo.getInfo() );
        System.out.println( annotation.value());

        //We're not changing the return
        return methodReturn;
    }
}
```

If I change the abstract class to not include `TargetType` and remove the abstract method, then it's only called once.

How do I keep that base class's generics and the abstract method but prevent it being called twice?

NOTE: I also tried the following, but it was still called twice:

```
@Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(MyAnnotation) && target(hasSomeInfo)")
```

Comment: Could you use `execution(* *.*(..))` instead? What happens?

Comment: Remove @Component on top of subclass. see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900905/spring-aop-advice-is-called-twice

Comment: @Barath when i door that, spring never calls the aspect class